# how to get previous page gridview's value

Tags: asp.net, gridview

In my grid view I want that when user click on activate then it navigate to activate.aspx page. And I want to retrieve three values from previous page to activate.aspx page.
My code is:

```
    if (this.Page.PreviousPage != null)
    {
        int rowIndex = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["RowIndex"]);
        GridView GridView1 = (GridView)this.Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("GridView1");
        GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[rowIndex];
        Label1.Text = row.Cells[3].Text;
        Label2.Text = row.Cells[2].Text;
        Label3.Text = row.Cells[2].Text;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("insert into login values('" + Label1.Text + "','" + Label2.Text + "','" + Label3.Text + "')",con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
      }
```

Markup:

```
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="Larger" HeaderText="Activate/Delete" ItemStyle-Width="150px">
                <ItemTemplate>                    
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="linkbutton1" runat="server" Text="Activate" PostBackUrl='<%# "activate.aspx?RowIndex=" + Container.DataItemIndex %>' ></asp:LinkButton>              
                    <span onclick="return confirm('Are You sure want to Delete?')">
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="linkbutton2" runat="server" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </span>
                </ItemTemplate>    
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

But I'm unable to retrieve previous page value.

Pls Help me.

Comment: why not pass the data as query string in the url itself?

Comment: can u pls tell me with examplle

Answer (score 0):

you are navigating your current page to **activate.aspx** through *PostBackUrl*. 
it basically works as **Response.Redirect("");** and in this the memory got released for previous page.
You should try to navigate through **Server.Transfer("activate.aspx",true);** from your current page's backend code using RowCommand of GridView.

**Aspx page markup :**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
            onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="Larger" HeaderText="Activate/Delete"
                    ItemStyle-Width="150px">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="linkbutton1" runat="server" Text="Activate" CommandName="Redirect"
                            CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "RowIndex") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                        <span onclick="return confirm('Are You sure want to Delete?')">
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="linkbutton2" runat="server" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
                        </span>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

**.cs page Code :**

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Redirect")
        {
            String yourId="What ever id you want pass";
            Server.Transfer("activate.aspx?RowIndex=" + yourId, true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Now I'm getting error that input string is not in correct format for the the following line: int rowIndex = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["RowIndex"]);

Comment: Code :  Server.Transfer("activate.aspx?RowIndex=" + email +mob, true);

Comment: Dear you should get rowindex using **CommandArgument**.
use this - 
**Server.Transfer("activate.aspx?RowIndex="+e.CommandArgument);**
   then follow your .cs page code

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few ways of passing data from 1 page to another.

If you want to use query string, you can add the variables to your existing column:

`<ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# "~/activate.aspx?RowIndex="  + Container.DataItemIndex + "&v1=" +  Eval("<prop>") + "&v2=" +  Eval("<prop2>") %>'>Activate</asp:HyperLink>
                    </ItemTemplate>`

- Replace v1 & v2 query string variables with the names you need.
- Replace  &  with the properties used to bind the data in the gridview for the columns you need.
- Since you don't need postback url, you can use the hyperlink as shown above.

If you want to use previous page, then when binding the gridview to a datasource; store the value of data source in a public property and then access the property through the PreviousPage property.

One more way to do this would be through the use of `Session` variables.

You can read about all of these here on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="linkbutton1" runat="server" Text="Activate" CommandArgument="linkbutton1" PostBackUrl='<%# "activate.aspx?RowIndex=" + Container.DataItemIndex %>' ></asp:LinkButton>
```

Put Command Argument like that.